# load automaticaly a view without clicking on href with ui-view angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to create a nav bar with 3 links 
I would like to get page.1 at the first time without clicking on page.1 ui-sref, 
i have like html:

```
  <nav>
        <a ui-sref="page.1">Search</a>
        <a ui-sref="page.2">Results</a>
        <a ui-sref="page.3">Detail</a>
      </nav>
     <ui-view></ui-view>
```

My states are defined as follows:

```
angular.module('scrollDemo', ['ui.router'])
.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('page.1', {
      url: '/page1',
      templateUrl: '/Page1.html'
    })
    .state('page.2', {
      url: '/page2',
      templateUrl: '/Page2.html'
    })
    .state('page.3', {
      url: '/page3',
      templateUrl: '/Page3.html'
    });
})
```

How can i procced ?

Comment: Try to redirect by $state.go(**YourStateNameHere**). eg: Home.Page1 Hope it will help.

Comment: i used you method like this  myApp.run(function($rootScope, $modal) {
 
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {if(toState.name == 'home.stateA'){
    $state.go('home.stateA.page1');
  
  }}
but it doesn't load, where can i use  $state.go??

Comment: Worked now, i wrote i wrong name of state , but your solution with $state.go(YourStateNameHere) worked !

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/path');` to set the detault path.

```
angular.module('scrollDemo', ['ui.router'])
.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/page.1');

  $stateProvider
    .state('page.1', {
      url: '/page1',
      templateUrl: '/Page1.html'
    })
    .state('page.2', {
      url: '/page2',
      templateUrl: '/Page2.html'
    })
    .state('page.3', {
      url: '/page3',
      templateUrl: '/Page3.html'
    });
})
```

Comment: and if i had as current state /home , how can i proceed?

Comment: change to `/home/page.1`

Comment: not working ! even with /home/page.1 and i tried also $urlRouterProvider.when('/home, '/page.1'); but not working also

Comment: can you create a plnkr

Comment: actually the code is very complicated to move it in plnkr, but the idea that i want to implement is : i have a button in the home state that go to anather page A with state stateA where there are the nav with page.1 page.2 and page.3 , the issue that i would like to show page.1 when i click on the button, now it load only the empty page with the 3 links.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154692/discussion-between-selma-and-sachila-ranawaka).

Answer (score 0):

You seem like you want to immediately go to `/page.1` when your application is loaded, what you can do is the following :

```
angular.module('scrollDemo', ['ui.router'])
.run(function($location) {
    $location.path('/page1');
});
```

This will automatically change the path of your application to the desired one right after everything is loaded.

Comment: no not when my application is loaded, Actually  i have a button in the home state that go to anather page A with state stateA where there are the nav with page.1 page.2 and page.3 , the issue that i would like to show page.1 when i click on the button, now it loads only the empty page with the 3 links